# NetlifyCMS - Collection content not found

Tags: webpack, gulp, content-management-system, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm using https://github.com/netlify-templates/kaldi-hugo-cms-template

I created a new collection ("pages") at config.yml and .md files are located at site/content. Front-end of the site is looking fine at localhost and at Netlify. At localhost:3000/admin also displays my "Pages" and I can edit them, but when I go to mysite.netlify.com/admin/#collections/pages I only see "Loading Entries".

Here's my collection

```html
collections: # A list of collections the CMS should be able to edit
  - name: "pages"
    label: "Site pages"
    folder: "site/content"
    create: true #
    fields:
      - {label: Title, name: title, widget: string}
      - {label: Description, name: description, widget: string}
      - {label: Intro, name: intro, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Description, name: description, widget: markdown}, {label: Subheading, name: subheading, widget: string}, {label: Primary call-to-action url, name: url, widget: string}, {label: Primary call to action, name: cta, widget: string}, {label: Secondary call-to-action url, name: url2, widget: string}, {label: Secondary call-to-action, name: cta2, widget: string}, {label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: list, fields: [{label: Head, name: head, widget: string}, {label: Text, name: text, widget: markdown}]}]}
      - {label: Outro, name: outro, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: list, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Text, name: text, widget: markdown}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try "mysite.netlify.com/admin/" (note the trailing slash). A lot of Hugo installs experience Hugo outputting both admin.html and admin/index.html, and only the latter will work.